# Indoor Maps for IOS/android

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps, indoor-positioning-system

I want to create indoor map for a mall. I am using Beacons for getting positions and navigating for shortest paths. I dont need gps or any other wifi. What i need is:

1. I need to know how to create maps which can zoom in and zoom out like google maps.
2. I want to draw paths dyanamically when the user searches for it, so i need to keep in mind this functionality while creating maps.

Any body helps, Thanks in advance.

[Note: I studied google maps , but i cant use google map indoor functionality for some reasons. I also dont want to use any API which needs to be subscribed]

Comment: Make your own maps and overlay base map using tile scheme.

Comment: Thankx @Babar...Can u explain a little more

Comment: @WasimAhmed: have you got any working solution?

Comment: I also want to draw route as you have mentioned. I can see that my current beacon is moving as my device moves. But I am confused that how to draw route as device moves.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create indoor map for a mall.

For creating an `indoor map` for any specific place *(your example: mall store)*, you can **draw your** `map` and include it as a `background image`. Then using `beacons` you have to calculate your distance from them and *draw your path based on `x` and `y` coordinates*.

> I need to know how to create maps which can zoom in and zoom out like google maps.

You can implement *`zoom on pinch`* on your `image (map image)`

> I want to draw paths dyanamically when the user searches for it, so i need to keep in mind this functionality while creating maps.

As i mentioned above, you have to draw your path based on `x and y coordinates`. You can suppose that image's *top-left* corner is the `intial coordinate(0,0)` and assign that to `x=0, y=0`. While you are moving, you make a calculation based on those `coordinates` and update `UI`

Comment: Thankx for your reply..How about 3D map? and Multi stores? Using images are not enought for these features

Comment: I dont have any idea about that

Comment: @WasimAhmed I think you are talking about panorama view. Well i suggest you to use what google already have!

Comment: Google has mentioned clearly that they can edit, remove or block the maps ..They can also change the policy..so i cant take the risk as this is a client project

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to Google's tools for drawing and rendering maps (indoor or otherwise) would be Mapbox, who just recently updated their mobile SDK offering. https://www.mapbox.com/developers/